# read from file, process and write to another file with multi-processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to come up with a script that reads from a file, processes the string and writes it to another file using multi-processing.

This is what I came up with til now:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

input = open('input.txt', 'r')
output = open('output.txt', 'w+')

writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=SOME_HEADER)
writer.writeheader()

def write_into_file(line):
    # do some processing to line
    writer.writerow(processed_line)

    #counter for debugging
    global c
    c += 1
    if c % 10000 == 0:
        print c

c = 0
pool = Pool(processes=4)
pool.map(write_into_file, input)

input.close()
output.close()
```

When this scripts runs I get all four processes to read the files in parallel but they are all writing (and I am guessing reading) the same lines - I get my counter print for debugging four times.

What do I need to change to make the processes pick up each time the "next" line and process it (I don't care if the line-order changes...)

Comment: `writerow` is **not** atomic across processes so it's perfectly possible that two such operations overlap and munge up the output file.  Cross-process locks are costly; I suspect that once they're properly in place there will be hardly any speedup from multiprocessing, at best.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a problem with isolation, not atomicity? Either way, this is going to be a problematic approach with very garbled output. I ran into a similar problem a while ago and just dumped things to Mongo, instead, and then pulled them out when my process had finished.

Comment: @AlexMartelli I can live with an output file with a different order. How can I do it, while losing the ordering?

Comment: The global variable `c` is not shared between processes. When each process has printed "10000", you'd actually have processed 40000 lines. However Alex Martelli is right in that it's not a very good idea to write to a same file from different processes without locking. One line might even be written in the middle of the other. 
You would probably want to process the lines in different processes, retrieve those results in the main process, and only write to the file from the main process.

Comment: @ArturGaspar I see your point but in this case I can't parallelize writing operations into a file. BTW any suggestions how to debug it correctly?

Comment: @cheeech Have the `write_into_file` function take a tuple as argument, this tuple would contain a line number and the line itself. Then `enumerate()` the input argument to `pool.map()`. This way you can know the original line number from within each process.